# google map geocode and setCenter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-ui

i have this strange phenomenon but first the code

## html

```
<div ng-app='maptesting'>
       <div ng-controller="MapCtrl">
            <div id="map_canvas" ui-map="myMap" 
              style="height:300px;width:400px;border:2px solid #777777;margin:3px;     
              border:1px solid" 
              ui-options="mapOptions" 
              ui-event="{'map-idle' : 'onMapIdle()'}"
    >
</div>
```

## JavaScript

```
angular.module('maptesting', ['ui.map','ui.event']);
function MapCtrl($scope) {
    var ll = new google.maps.LatLng(30.9000, 40.2740);
    $scope.mapOptions = {
        center: ll,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var geocoder= new google.maps.Geocoder();

var map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),      
    $scope.mapOptions);

var address='los angeles';
geocoder.geocode({'address':address},function(results,status){
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
        alert(address);
        alert(results[0].geometry.location);
        alert($scope.myMap);
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        test=results[0].geometry.location;
        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
    }else{
        alert(status);
    }   
});


$scope.onMapIdle = function() {
    if ($scope.myMarkers === undefined){    
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.myMap,
            position: ll
        });
        $scope.myMarkers = [marker, ];
    }
};

$scope.markerClicked = function(m) {
    window.alert("clicked");
};

}
```

everything seems to be ok, marker, zoom, drag, the only things that doesn't go well is the map.setCenter, the map always sets his center in the ll coordinates, can anyone help me?

here you can find a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eb8Fd/1/ and as you can see the center isn't in California, instead is in Iraq, and if you zoom rapidly it seems there are two maps.

Comment: What `results[0].geometry.location` contains? Maybe caused by that result element is not a `LatLng` object?

Comment: Can you put this into a JSFiddle so we can diagnose the issue?

Comment: no it is a LatLng, i'have seen it with the alerts

Comment: Would you take 1 minute to indent your code correctly and remove errors?

Comment: Is the marker displaying in the correct position? Also your .onMapIdle function will never create a new marker as the object results is local to the geocoder function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 `google.maps.Map`-instances there(1 created via `ui.map` and another created in  `MapCtrl`).

Remove the creation of the 2nd instance and use this code:

```
//Markers should be added after map is loaded
    var address='los angeles';
    geocoder.geocode({'address':address},function(results,status){
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
            alert(address);
            alert(results[0].geometry.location);
            alert($scope.myMap);
            $scope.myMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            test=results[0].geometry.location;
            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
              map: $scope.myMap,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        }else{
            alert(status);
        }   
    });
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/eb8Fd/6/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/eb8Fd/6/)